# edit and rephrase or ask new question?

Tags: discussion, editing, etiquette, asking-questions, closing

If neither the commentators nor I (meanwhile) are happy with my question, should I edit it completely or post a new one? (how do I close the fist one then?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> should I edit it completely or post a new one

You should decide whether it's about content or about presentation.

- If you just want to rephrase the question to make it clearer — then, please, don't post a new question; edit the old one (even if it requires a complete rewrite, more or less).
- But, if you decided that you actually want to ask a *mathematically* completely different question — then it should be posted as a new question, obviously.

And if you really want to close some of your questions just flag it for moderator attention.